# How to resize view when in-call status bar appears

Tags: ios, autolayout

OK I have searched high and low and seem unable to find an explanation for how an app is supposed to respond when the In-Call Status Bar appears or disappears.

I see the following behaviour:
- The view controllers respond perfectly when they are visible and the status bar appears or dissapears
- However when navigating to the ViewControllers one of them responds correctly the first time by resizing itself if the status bar is present but none of the others appear willing to - they all will then adjust their sizes correctly when the status bar subsequently appears or disappears.

The fact that they resize properly when they are visible in response to the status bar changes seems to indicate that the auto layout constraints are set correctly.

Does anyone have any suggestion how I can force the view to adjust when it becomes visible.  Alternately does anyone have any sample code to put in the `func statusBarFrameWillChange(note: NSNotification)` callback ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I just found something that seems to work - seems strange that iOS does not simply take care of it - must be something wrong with the view controllers !?!

```
/// Handle In-Call Status Bar or other changes
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.view.frame = (self.view.superview?.bounds)!
}
```